# ClickOnce: Check manifest file before updating

Tags: clickonce, manifest

In my application , I check for application updates programmatically. 
(according to [How to: Check for Application Updates Programmatically Using the ClickOnce Deployment API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404263.aspx)) ,but I want also to know before the update, which dll's were changed (by checking dll version) in order to decide whether the update is relevant for current user.

As usual , you have to check for update so:

`UpdateCheckInfo info = ad.CheckForDetailedUpdate();`

But, UpdateCheckInfo does not contain update content information, I want to get the manifest which contains relevant data.

Do you have any idea how could I check update content before updating?

Answer (score 0):

I found no way to do it. 
Now, 8 month later I just can tall you what I did instead ...

Our solution is managing dll version in the db. when application has to check for clickonce  update, the version in the db checked also.

A major disadvantage that we should maintain the database dll's versions.